# How to get an entity reference's field in a database query

Tags: entities, database

I have a simple query right now, a `db_select` that returns the fields I need, but the problem is that one field is `entity reference` and I don't know how to get its fields from the `db_select`.

The other thing is that entity reference I'm talking about has another entity reference in it, and I would like to get its fields too.

Comment: Just use a `JOIN`. If it's an entity reference field the column in the field table will be called `field_FIELD_NAME_target_id`. If you want more specific advice, it'd be best to include the code and more explanation of exactly what doesn't work

Comment: @Clive, thank you, I'll try the normal join with the name of the field you provided.

Comment: @Clive, I changed the entity reference to node reference but still I can't select fields of that content type in the node reference from my `db_select`